# Pagination in asp.net using Datapager - next,previous button

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="listTexts" runat="server" OnDataBound="listTexts_DataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                <span id="CommentedText">
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment") %>
                    </span>
            </div>
</ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
<div>
 <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="listTexts" PageSize="10">
<Fields>
        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowNextPageButton="false" />
         <asp:NumericPagerField />
        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
</Fields>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the code present in my .ascx file 
The event for listTexts_DataBound is in .cs (code behhind )file

```
protected void listTexts_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DataPager.Visible = (DataPager.PageSize < DataPager.TotalRowCount);
 }
```

When I run the code I have to press next or previous button twice in order to move to either next or previous page.
I need this to happen in first click itself. 
Say there are 100 pages and there are 10 numbers with previous in the first ant next in the end, I have to click twice to move page from 1 to 2 when I click next and from page 10 to 9 when I click previous However the rest navigation i.e. from 2 to 9 will happen in 1st click only.

Please guide.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use OnPreRender="DataPager_PreRender" and in this event we can assign the data and bind.

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListView"
PageSize="5" OnPreRender="DataPager_PreRender">
```

This should be the code behind :

```
protected void DataPager_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            ListView.DataSource = db.datasource();
            ListView.DataBind();
}
```

this solves the issue